# Any material that could help me calculate the surface/longitudinal/transversal modes in an isotropic semiconductor?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, phonons, quantum-dots

Basically a homework question, but I don't actually have a homework to give in. I just do it out of curiosity.

I would like to know if there are any good materials out there that could ilustrate to me how to calculate the phonon modes (surface, longitudinal, transversal) in an isotropic semiconductor quantum dot?

Comment: Do you want to know about phonons in an isotropic semiconductor (an infinitely large crystal lattice) or about the vibrational modes of a semiconductor quantum dot (a nanostructure of finite size)?

Comment: Both, but with more emphasis on the vibrational modes of a semiconductor quantum dot.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, what you are asking is not a homework question.

Never mind the vibrational modes of a quantum dot; you can't even analytically find the vibrational modes of a cube of jello (see below excerpt --- you can skip the abstract and move to the introduction).

With the quantum dot, your only option is some sort of computer simulation. Depending on the size of your structure, a molecular dynamics simulator like [LAMMPS](https://lammps.sandia.gov/) might be a good approach.

The difficult part about the cube of jello/quantum dot is that it has finite extent and, most importantly, free boundary conditions. Infinitely large lattices are actually much easier to deal with. Basically, you need to find the interatomic potential for your material. After you have that, finding the modes basically boils down to taking various derivatives of that potential and doing some mathematical manipulations. For a reference, see J. M. Ziman's *Electrons and Phonons* chapter 1. It's messy but doesn't require any super advanced math.

The question is: how do you get the interatomic potential? If you want to do it from scratch, your only options are computational. There are various software packages that can help with this, such as [Quantum Espresso](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/resources/tutorials/shanghai-2013/hands-on-phonons/phonons_tutorial_shanghai1.pdf) or [Atomic Simulation Environment](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/phonons.html). [phonopy](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/) is a front end that can interface to various backends (including the two I listed).

Sometimes you can get away with using a simple analytic interatomic potential. IIRC, the [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) works well for simple materials (like solid Argon).

[image: Excerpt from Quantum Chaology in Quartz by Mark Oxborrow and Clive Ellegaard]

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely extremely helpful! Would I abuse of your courtesy if I would also ask about the phonons in an isotropic semiconductor aswell? Like, for example, if I would like to know more about the phonons inside a isotropic semiconductor quantum dot of radius R? The crystal should be large enough that the Born-Huang approximation works, I think.

Comment: Could you define "isotropic semiconductor"? Also, there are two types of quantum dots. Are you interested in the semiconductor nanoparticles or the transistor-like nanostructures used for quantum computation? (I'm guessing that you're asking about the former, but I just want to be sure.)

Comment: Right, I am extremely sorry. English is my 3rd language and my understanding of the subject is not the strongest, so perhaps that's why I am struggling. I have found some material that I can refer to, and I hope this will help me clarify my issue. A brief example is given in "Ruppin and Englman (1968): Optical Lattice Vibrations in Finite Ionic Cristals : I". Whilst I understood the given generalisation for a finite diatomic crystal, I do not understand the first of the given examples, for a sphere, and what the difference would be from a sphere to a "Spherical Quantum Dot".